# mount.cifs -o vers=1.0,sec=ntlm fails with No such file or directory

Tags: samba, cifs

**Note**: this is **NOT** a duplicate of [mount.cifs fails with mount error(2): No such file or directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162199), read until the end.

I'm trying to mount a SMBv1 volume on Ubuntu 20.04.
With `smbclient` I'm able to list the shared directories this way:

```
smbclient -L //192.168.1.1/usbkey -U (myusername)
```

After adding the following options to /etc/samba/smb.conf:

```
   client min protocol = NT1
   ntlm auth = ntlmv1-permitted
   client use spnego = no
```

While, in **no way** I was able to mount the shared directory with `mount.cifs`, even if I added the flags `vers=1.0,sec=ntlm` as suggested by various answers like: [mount.cifs fails with mount error(2): No such file or directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162199)

I've tried:

```
1. mount.cifs -o vers=1.0,sec=ntlm,username=admin //192.168.1.1/usbkey /mnt/usbkey
2. mount.cifs -o vers=1.0,sec=ntlm,username=admin //192.168.1.1/usbkey$ /mnt/usbkey
3. mount.cifs -o username=admin,vers=1.0,sec=ntlm //192.168.1.1/usbkey /mnt/usbkey
4. mount.cifs -o vers=1.0,username=admin //192.168.1.1/usbkey /mnt/usbkey
5. mount.cifs -o username=admin,vers=1.0 //192.168.1.1/usbkey /mnt/usbkey
```

And nothing worked. First, it asks me the password and then I get every time:

```
mount error(2): No such file or directory
```

So, there must be **something else**, introduced recently, to be set in order to allow mounting of **unsecure** SAMBA v1 shared directories (I understand the security risks etc).

Interesting final note: if I enable full guest access (which means read/write) for the shared directory, than mount.cifs works. Therefore, it's still something related with authenication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, sorry for the spam, but I've found a solution to my problem.
What happened is that, with this configuration (not allowing guest access), I don't have root shared directory called `usbkey`, but instead separate shared directories at root-level.

And, ironically, the `No such file or directory` was, for once, meaningful.
Sadly, I'm used to ignore it, because of all the cases where, because of things like security policies, `mount` fails with the same error.

I hope that other people hitting my problem nowadays (with SMBv1 deprecated) could benefit from this question.

Comment: Could you share the final mount command that worked?