# mounting smb windows share using cifs

Tags: 20.04, mount, samba, cifs

I want to mount a windows share on Ubuntu 20.04.
I created a directory `mkdir /media/aus`
I have the following in my `/etc/fstab` file:

```
//IP_ADDRESS_OF_THE_SHARE/aus /media/aus cifs sec=krb5i,user,noauto 0 0
```

as you can see I'm getting the credentials using `krb5` and the ticket is available (I have verified with `klist`), also `smbclient IP_ADDRESS_OF_THE_SHARE` works fine.
But when I open the file explorer and click on my mounting point I get the error: `mount error(2): No such file or directory`

Comment: It's really not clear what you are trying to achieve. Are you saying that you are navigating to /media/aus? why would you wish to do that?

Comment: Check also this similar question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162199/mount-cifs-fails-with-mount-error2-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: I have seen this question, it didn't solve my problem. If I mount my share that way it works fine without specifying any smb version, but I should give my username and password, what I want to achieve is to mount this share globally, that means when a user logs in and authenticates with krb5, the krb5 ticket would be used in fstab to mount the share automatically.

Comment: I would leave out `sec=...` option, and add `username=foo,passwd=hellO` assuming `foo\hellO` user is sharing `\aus` on windows .